# Parse Android Room Generated Schema to Actual SQLite Script

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to create a .db file to pre populate my Android Room database but the database/schema is huge so I am trying to find a way not to do it manually. Basically I want to do the following:

1. Generate the database schema for Room (done!)
2. Generate the SQLite commands from the schema without needing to be reading the schema and copying and pasting all the scripts found in it
3. Create the database on some SQL client
4. Populate the database with the default data and generate a .db file from it to add into my app to be used by Room.

I need help on step 2. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create the Entities and @Database with the appropriate Entities. (you've done this)
2. Compile/make the project <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>F9</kbd>.
3. Switch to Android View.
4. Look in the Java (generated) folder and open the subfolders. One will have the @Database class suffixed with _Impl. Open that class and find the createAllTables method it contains the exact SQL required. Note you do not need the room_master_table nor the insert into the table.

Here's an example (just the one Entity/Table) :-

[image]

- no need to create the room_master_table or insert the hash value into it (this is used for verification of schema changes)

**Alternately**

1. Create the Entities, @Database and a basic @Dao (perhaps with just a query of a table).
2. Have an Activity query the DB and it will then be created when the App is run.
3. Close the database (not necessarily required).
4. Run the App.
5. Use Device Explorer to locate the database file(s)(data/data/<package_name>/databases folder).
6. If file suffixed with -wal exists and is not 0 bytes then copy all three files to a suitable location. If no -wal (or 0 bytes) file then just need to copy the database file itself (it wouldn't hurt to copy the -wal and -shm files though).

- If the -wal exists and has data that data belongs to the database so you must copy the -wal and to be extra sure the -shm file. Closing the database should commit the changes which is a full commit (and the -wal file should then be empty).

  - note creating tables etc will first be applied uncommitted to the -wal file.

**Alternative Example**

In an activity:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()
        dao.getTodoCount() //<<<<<< query just to open DB and thus create table via onCreate 
        db.close(); //<<<<< Close to commit WAL file
    }
}
```

@Database is in this case is :-

```
@Database(entities = [Todo::class],version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = synchronized(context) {
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context, TheDatabase::class.java, "tot.db")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries() //<<<<<<<<<< allow main thread run
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

- **note** .allowMainThreadQueries() simplifies matters.

App is run. And then Database Inspector used to confirm DB (not required) :-
[image]

Device File Explorer used to locate DB :-

[image]

Right click file and Save As :-

[image]

Open with SQLite tool (Navicat in this case) :-

[image]

:-

[image]